# Erro de remote: true usando no RAILS, para POST de um arquivo JS

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou com um problema em meu código, quero que o Rails faça remote: true do "Login" com uma classe e um id conforme abaixo, mas o servidor passa um GET, mas quero quebusque no controller o format.js para enviar uma função JS do tipo POST, preciso saber se o código da minha view/index.html.erb abaixo esta correto:

Na view/index.html.erb

no controller:
class HomeController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Ficou um pouco confuso a pergunta, mas o que eu entendi é que você deseja que o método `index` seja um `POST` em vez de `GET`.

Por padrão o método `index` é utilizado para requisições `GET`. Por isso o que eu recomendo é você criar um outro método e o declare no seu arquivo `routes.rb` ele como um POST. E esse método pode dar um `render` do método `index`

```
def search
     render :action => :index
end
```